# Laravel Form: Input Button Not Showing HTML Icon

Tags: forms, laravel, button, laravel-blade, submit-button

I'm creating a button with Form at Laravel:

```
{!! Form::submit('<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>', ["class"=>"btn btn-default"]) !!}
```

The button text becomes:

```
<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
```

I see only this string, not the icon: how to fix it?

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: the button didn't show the icon

Comment: Care to add the `fa fa-trash` css code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `Form::button` instead of `Form::submit`:

```
{{ Form::button('<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-default'] )  }}
```

It will create a `button` tag with type `submit` instead of an `input` tag.

This way the html of the icon should be rendered inside the tag content and should be visible.

Instead, by using an `input` tag like you are doing, the html string of the icon would be printend inside the `value` attribute of the `input` tag, and here it couldn't be rendered as valid html

Comment: yapp thats work, now i have new problem {{ Form::button('<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-default', 'onclick'=>'return confirm("Are you sure want to delete $size->size?")']) }} how to show the variable size? it's show just plain text

Comment: try this way: `'onclick' => 'return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete ' . $size->size . '?")'`